# Как отправить видео из приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio, share

хочу отправить видео, которое лежит на файлообменнике, в соц сети из приложения. То есть сделать кнопку "поделиться"

Прочитал много всего и нашел вариант сделать это через Activity_send. С текстом проблем не было, всё отправляется. А вот видео не могу

пытаюсь сделать так:

```
        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sharingIntent.type = "video/mp4"
        val uri = Uri.parse("https://.../video.mp4")
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Video")
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Video")
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

        startActivity(holder.context,Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Поделиться"), Bundle())
```

Comment: Может быть делиться ссылкой на видео? Тот же текст.

Comment: Нет, так как видео хранится на файлообменнике. и не хочется отправлять ссылку на видео из него